# FxCop + command line execution?

Tags: .net, fxcop, fxcopcmd

does anyone know how to or can provide the syntax for running FxCop via command line.

i want to set a task to run a defined rules.fxcop file (this is a empty project that i made with only a select set of rules enabled to reduce noise and check for things i am interested in)

can someone explain how i can accomplish this...

i am guessing i would need to get latest version of the code and compile the .dll first then somehow get the fxcop project to add the dll as a target and run the analysis. then i want the violations found exported via email or saved to a directory.

ideas?

Comment: This article seems relevant though probably doesn't do everything you want (no custom .fxcop): http://blog.runxc.com/post/2009/04/14/Calling-FxCop-from-MsBuild.aspx For email export you probably want a continuous integration msbuild task, also at that link.

Comment: using the custom made fxcop project is key because running all the fxcop rules n un-usable report filled with nonsense and false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like the following:

```
fxcopcmd.exe /project:"<path to your .fxcop file>" /file:"<path to your target DLL>" /out:"<path to output report>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you pony up and buy all new parts...

Try implementing continous integration with [CC.NET](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET).  In it you can integrate with NUnit, NDepend, NCover, and FxCop.  All of which can be e-mailed to you, displayed on a dashboard, or visible through a program in your tray.

Comment: the problem is not CI as i have TFS and can set nightly builds in there. the problem is in ccnet or tfs how do i get a build task to use a fxcop project where i predefine rules to check for and run these against my dll?

Comment: @kacalapy I'm not sure how to do this for TFS, though a quick search in google returned a lot of results, but for CC.NET it is very very easy... http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+FxCop